# Deleting a row from a referenced table

Tags: sql, join, delete-row

I have an application in which I need to delete a row. It works perfectly when I am deleting a user that still does not have a ***role*** assigned.

Here are the tables:

***users:***

```
user_id | user_name | password
------------------------------
   1    |   some    |   some
   2    |   some2   |   some2
   3    |   some3   |   some3
```

***roles:***

```
role_id | role_name 
-------------------
   1    | admin
   2    | member
```

***user_role:***

```
user_id | role_id
-----------------
   1    |   1
   2    |   2
   3    |   2
```

The problem is that I cannot delete them using

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = :id
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: *Why* can't you do that?  Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to delete a row from the user table when the user is not assigned a role, but you cannot delete one that has a role assigned, the problem is almost assuredly due to a *foreign key constraint* which is set to RESTRICT.

Information here, at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#Referential_Actions).

Whoever set up the database expressly prevented the deletion of a user from happening when the user had an assigned role.  If the deletion is permitted to go through without anything else happening (NO ACTION), then you would have a row in the `user_role` table referring to a non-existent user, and what fun would that be?  There are other possiblilties, e.g. deletion of a user could delete all corresponding roles (CASCADE).

If this is indeed your problem (constraint set to RESTRICT), then you need to physically delete the rows from the `user_role` table for the given user *first*, then you should be able to delete the user.

Comment: what if i change the constraint?

Comment: Sure, that should work, too.  Try it.  You didn't mention which database you are using in your question; it might be that different systems support different kinds of constraints so find the one that's best for your situation.